# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined in form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react component, but I cant find the reason of the error above, help appreciated

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Input} from 'antd';
import Form from '../../components/uielements/form';
import Button from '../../components/uielements/button';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';


const FormItem = Form.Item;

class CreateSiteCollectionForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {Alias:'',DisplayName:'', Description:''};
        this.handleChangeAlias = this.handleChangeAlias.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeDisplayName = this.handleChangeDisplayName.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeDescription = this.handleChangeDescription.bind(this);

    };

    handleChangeAlias(event){
        this.setState({Alias: event.target.value});
    }

    handleChangeDisplayName(event){
        this.setState({DisplayName: event.target.value});
    }

    handleChangeDescription(event){
        this.setState({Description: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                let data = new FormData();
                //Append files to form data
                data.append(JSON.stringify({"Alias": this.state.Alias,
                 "DisplayName": this.state.DisplayName, 
                 "Description": this.state.Description
                }));

                const options = {
                  method: 'post',
                  body: data,
                  config: {
                    headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                  }
                };

                adalApiFetch(fetch, "/SiteCollections", options)
                  .then(response =>{
                    if(response.status === 204){
                        Notification(
                            'success',
                            'Site collection created',
                            ''
                            );
                     }else{
                        throw "error";
                     }
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                    Notification(
                        'error',
                        'Site collection not created',
                        error
                        );
                    console.error(error);
                });
            }
        });      
    }

    render() {
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        const formItemLayout = {
        labelCol: {
            xs: { span: 24 },
            sm: { span: 6 },
        },
        wrapperCol: {
            xs: { span: 24 },
            sm: { span: 14 },
        },
        };
        const tailFormItemLayout = {
        wrapperCol: {
            xs: {
            span: 24,
            offset: 0,
            },
            sm: {
            span: 14,
            offset: 6,
            },
        },
        };
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Alias" hasFeedback>
                {getFieldDecorator('Alias', {
                    rules: [
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your alias',
                        }
                    ]
                })(<Input name="alias" id="alias" onChange={this.handleChangeAlias} />)}
                </FormItem>
                <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Display Name" hasFeedback>
                {getFieldDecorator('displayname', {
                    rules: [
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your display name',
                        }
                    ]
                })(<Input name="displayname" id="displayname" onChange={this.handleChangedisplayname} />)}
                </FormItem>
                <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Description" hasFeedback>
                {getFieldDecorator('description', {
                    rules: [
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your description',
                        }
                    ],
                })(<Input name="description" id="description"  onChange={this.handleChangeDescription} />)}
                </FormItem>

                <FormItem {...tailFormItemLayout}>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                        Create modern site
                    </Button>
                </FormItem>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

const WrappedCreateSiteCollectionForm = Form.create()(CreateSiteCollectionForm);
export default WrappedCreateSiteCollectionForm;
```

Comment: Do you have the line number of the error?

Comment: You need to post the full error description for context

Comment: You should `bind` your event-handler or they get executed on a differrent/`null` object. All of them, because I already see the next question coming: "why doesn't setState update the state in my component." You can do that by using Arrow-function, the `this.fn = this.fn.bind(this)` pattern in the constructor, or one of the many autobind decorator out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use arrow functions for your handlers to keep the `this` context problem away.

According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target.

So, in your components:

```
<Form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
...
onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeAlias(e)}
...
onChange={(e) => this.handleChangedisplayname(e)}
...
onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeDescription(e)}
```

And, don't bind in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {Alias:'',DisplayName:'', Description:''};
};
```

**Problems with inline functions, and arrow functions**

There are many articles on the subject, and I don't want to start a debate here, since it has already been debated for long.

If you are having problems of re-rendering with this solution, but think arrow functions are easier (to write, to read, to understand, to bind, etc) then have a look at [Reflective-bind](https://github.com/flexport/reflective-bind), which solves this problems in a very easy way.

These articles are important to have a good understanding on what inline functions and arrow functions do, and why you should use or not use them in your project:

- [A good article to read](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1)
- [Facebook's Github long debate on this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9851)
- [Official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)
- [Example result in babel for bind and arrow functions](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=%2F%2F%20Declare%20a%20method%20as%20an%20instance%20property%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20foo%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log('foo')%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Binding%20a%20method%20as%20an%20instance%20property%0Aclass%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.bar%20%3D%20this.bar.bind(this)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20bar()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('bar')%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true)
- [Motivation for Reflective bind](https://flexport.engineering/ending-the-debate-on-inline-functions-in-react-8c03fabd144)

Comment: nice one, this seems to be a cleaner solution

Comment: It also unnecessarily wraps your function in a function causing unnecessary code bloat. Setting the context of the function in terms of `this` is exactly what `bind` is for. You could use es2016 class arrow functions, some light reading here about them https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1

Answer (score 1):

You need to `bind` `handleSubmit` to `this`

`this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)` in constructor

Answer (score 0):

Bind your handleSubmit in the constructor like so

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {Alias:'',DisplayName:'', Description:''};
        this.handleChangeAlias = this.handleChangeAlias.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeDisplayName = this.handleChangeDisplayName.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeDescription = this.handleChangeDescription.bind(this);

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this); // Bind it
    };
```